# Exiting the terminal vs Closing the terminal

Tags: 18.04, bash, process

**Context:-**

I am running a process in bash with `&` appended i.e in background mode. The process has a `while(1)` i.e it will run forever. My bash is parent and my process becomes the child. I want to learn how Kernel handles the child when parent is terminated.

**Observations:-**

1. If I exit the terminal (using `exit` command from the terminal), `/lib/systemd/systemd --user` becomes the parent process of the child
2. If I kill the terminal process (using `kill`) from another terminal, same result as above
3. If I close the terminal using cross icon, child process gets terminated too

**Question:-**

How is closing different from killing/exiting?

Comment: Which version (20.04.x LTS?) and which flavour (Ubuntu Desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu ... Xubuntu?) are you running? Which terminal emulator are you running (gnome-terminal or ... ?) What child process is it (is it a compiled program, a shellscript ...; is it running in its own window or in the background or in the original terminal window)?

Comment: @sudodus, my mistake for the lack of information. Here: Ubuntu Desktop, 18.04.5 LTS, gnome-terminal, compiled program running in the terminal's window

Answer (score 1):

[There are different kind of signals in linux](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Standard-Signals.html#Standard-Signals). When you `exit` terminal, the signal sent is different from the signal which is sent when you close terminal by clicking on `x`. Try going through [termination signals](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html) to find how closing and exiting terminal is different from each other.

Comment: I went through it, and I still don't know what signal is sent when we close the terminal emulator window, or what signal is sent when we type `exit` in the terminal. Can you please elaborate and explain what signals are sent and the difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

The process launched like this `./myprocess &` are child of the parent `bash` process opened by the terminal program. The sign `&` wont help you to close the terminal window before the end of a long process.

What you are looking for is the command `nohup`

```
user@host:~$ nohup bash -c '/path/to/myprocess'
```

More info :
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/en/man1/nohup.1.html
Some Examples:
https://linuxhint.com/nohup_command_linux/

Comment: I only need to know the reason behind my observations. To make sense of what I am observing. I think it is about the signal that is dispatched to the processes.

Comment: @Saad Abdul Majid :see first part of my answer, closing the terminal window kills the parent bash process

Answer (score 0):

I used `ping` in a `gnome-terminal` window and I can confirm your observations. I think it is problematic, that a process can be left running without anywhere to communicate. I will try to interpret what I notice (*but I do not claim that I understand why*, maybe to allow programs with an own GUI to work without `nohup` after exit from `bash`, when started in a terminal window).

- When I `exit` I am exiting from `bash` running in the terminal window, and `ping` continues to run, but has nowhere to write.
- When I `kill` the process, I kill the **`bash`** process in the terminal window. I did not find an explicit `gnome-terminal` process to kill, because the process `/usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server` runs them all. I am not sure that this is what you were doing, but it is what I guess.
- When I close the window (with the x button) I exit from the window process (which in turn forces its child processes to stop including `bash` and `ping`). This is an obvious difference from the two previous cases.

---

When I do the corresponding exercise with `xterm`, there will be a separate process with the name 'xterm'.

- When I `exit` I am exiting from `bash` running in the terminal window, and `ping` continues to run, but has nowhere to write.
- When I `kill` the process, I kill the `xterm` process of the terminal window,  (which in turn forces its child processes to stop, including `bash` and `ping`).
- When I close the window (with the x button) I exit from the window process (which in turn forces its child processes to stop, including `bash` and `ping`).

---

You know already, that you can use `nohup` (together with `&`) if you want the child process to continue after closing the terminal window, where child process was started.

---

Edit 1: Final comment:

From `man bash`

> If  a  command  is terminated by the control operator &, the shell
> executes the command in the background in a subshell.  The shell does
> not wait for the command to finish, and the return status is 0.

We have noticed that there is no signal to stop the subshell and the process started in/from that subshell, when `bash` is exited, at least not when run in a terminal window. But the calling terminal window is closed. I think, that after bash is exited, the terminal window no longer knows of the subshell and the process started in/from that subshell, and therefore it cannot stop them.

Edit 2: I asked for help at [Unix & Linux - Please read the answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/673353/how-is-closing-a-terminal-window-different-from-killing-exiting).